# Distributed Availability Group Failover Issue

Tags: sql-server, distributed-availability-groups

I have created Distributed Availability group set up as below:

In Data center A, created 2 node AG1 setup (Synchronous) in Datacenter B, created 2 node AG2 setup (asynchronous).

Created Distributed AG setup (synchronous) on top of these two AGs and it is working fine.

When i am executing Failover command (on Primary of DC A) to failover manually it is not failing over properly, it changes the role of AG1 as secondary but shows disconnected from AG2.

I executed 
`ALTER Availability group DistAG FAIlOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` command on Primary of AG1.

please help to clarify if any config problem is there or i need to follow certain steps to fail-over.

Comment: Did you set the role on the initial primary side to secondary, then do the failover at the initial secondary side? The steps you've taken and commands executed aren't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should run the following command on the primary of the secondary group.

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP <AG name> FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS;
```